# robot_state_publisher posting wrong tf tree (missing connections)

Tags: ros, robot-state-publisher, tf-tree, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear ROS community,

I have the following problem:

I'm trying to simulate a robotic leg using ROS kinetic and Gazebo.

In order to get information about the current frame of each link I'm using the `robot_state_publisher`. He's a subscriber of the `/joint_states` topic and also receives information from the parameter `robot_description` which is loaded as an parameter using the `xacro` file, which describes the leg construction with all it's links and joints. He then publishes to the topic `/tf`

When I use the `rqt_tf_tree` to check the tf_tree I have 3 unconnected tree structures as a result, two Joints are missing.
I first thought the xacro files would be incompleted, but I checked the  `robot_description` by using  `$ rosparam get /robot_description`

E.g.

```
<joint name="joint_B1" type=" continuous">
  <origin rpy="0 0.512690467 0" xyz="-0.05 -0.005 0"/>
  <parent link="upper_leg"/>
  <child link="connector_2"/>
  <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
  <dynamics friction="0"/>
  <limit effort="10" velocity="10"/>
</joint>
```

is one of the missing connections.

Do you guys have any suggestion where my problem could be?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285715/robot_state_publisher-posting-wrong-tf-tree-(missing-connections)/) by [JaFeKl](https://answers.ros.org/users/34185/jafekl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The missing connections were caused by missing transmission elements in the `xacro` file. I thought only transmission elments for the actuated joints are necessary, but it seems like this isn't the case. In order to get a right tf_tree, every non-fixed joints need to get a transmission element.

---

Originally posted by [JaFeKl](https://answers.ros.org/users/34185/jafekl/) with karma: 26 on 2018-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0